# "Access to the path is denied" when trying to delete DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am trying to run my program that has an auto-updating feature. When the update is triggered, it gets the new files from Azure Blob Storage, downloads them and then copies them to the folder where the application .exe is.

This works fine for most files, but one of the DLLs in my project seems to always fail when I try to replace it. I instead tried to rename the old file, copy the new one and then delete the old one, but this is giving me an "Access to path is denied" error in VS. Here is the code I am using to delete the files

`

```
string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string path = Regex.Replace(Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path), "Data.exe", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path);

            foreach(var filename in filePaths)
            {
                string file = filename.ToString();

                if(file.Contains("_old.dll"))
                {
                    File.Delete(file);
                }
            }
```

`

When it gets to a specific file in the Debug folder, it always throws this exception

> Access to the path '...' is denied.

Not sure why only this DLL is having problems, as I have several other DLLs that get copied and replaced with no issue. Is there a way to completely stop this DLL or remove it from memory, so we can ensure it is not being using by the application any longer?

I have tried stopping all threads in my application before copying the files but that seemed to not have an impact. The file is not read-only, and I also cannot delete it manually in Windows Explorer, as it says it is open in my application.

Comment: Getting a program to update itself is pretty hard. Any assemblies that have been loaded will be locked. That is why ASP.NET applications run using a [shadow copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/shadow-copy-assemblies). Most bootstrappers I have seen launch a separate process that does the update then relaunches the original program when complete.

Comment: If the updating/deleting is done by the program that you're updating then this is pretty much guaranteed to fail.  Just give up quickly when the delete fails, the *next* time you update you have much better odds of being able to delete the renamed file.